# Elastic search not return all fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index which name is news, here is the stored mapping in the elasticsearch:

```
{
   "news": {
      "mappings": {
         "newsdetail": {
            "properties": {
               "active": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "authorId": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "creationDate": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "iDate": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "iTime": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "isExclusive": {
                  "type": "boolean"
               },
               "itemId": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "languageId": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "lead": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "main": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "mainTitr": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "mediaType": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "newsType": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "pictureId": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "ref": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "subMain": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "subMainTitr": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "subtitle": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "text": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "title": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "video": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "viewCount": {
                  "type": "long"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

when I try to search in this index's data it returns this:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 69612,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "news",
            "_type": "newsdetail",
            "_id": "AU6Gt1fK36ANCl26_meY",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "itemId": 452,
               "pictureId": 452,
               "authorId": 1,
               "languageId": 1,
               "active": 1,
               "title": "خبر تستی",
               "main": 1,
               "mainTitr": 1,
               "subMain": 1,
               "subMainTitr": 1,
               "video": "ویدئوی تستی",
               "newsType": 3,
               "creationDate": "2014-06-09T18:38:47.203",
               "viewCount": 201,
               "isExclusive": false,
               "mediaType": 0
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

some of fields has missed. what should I do to see whole fields. note that I have not select fields and my request is `GET news/_search?pretty=true&size=1`

Comment: If those fields are not displayed, this means that when the document was indexed that field wasn't there, it was simply omitted.

Comment: no I have tested and I have ensured that those field has value

Comment: Then are you sure the mapping you posted is the one matching the data you showed? (here I refer to any non-stored fields)

Comment: yes buddy I have mapped the data with NEST library of .NET

Comment: :-) ok then. How did you test that those fields have value? Can you provide details about this in the post?

Comment: of course, I wrote a query like this `GET news/_search?q=text:sth` then it showed the text and lead field too

Comment: And are you sure the result returned for `q=text:sth` contains the same document as above? Meaning `"_index": "news",
            "_type": "newsdetail",
            "_id": "AU6Gt1fK36ANCl26_meY"`.

Comment: yes buddy. After retrieving result I search the Id in the table of Sql Server to see it's correctness

Comment: I was hoping you post some proofs of these statements, so I can double check them. Cannot help you further. One thing is certain: given that mapping and given you DO index those fields then you have to see the fields being displayed. What you describe is impossible. Good luck!